# Distinguishing between beginning-/end-of-word apostrophe and single close quotation mark

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Matthew Barnett's regex module for python.

I want to replace single quotes with other characters. While simple cases are easily dealt with, I fail when I try to work on this kind:

```
string = "I told them 'go check the dogs' den' but those dogs' den haters refused boldly: 'go check 'em yourself, lad'."
```

How can I distinguish those end-of-word and beginning-of-word apostrophes from the correct quote closer/opener?

It seems impossible, at least by regex only. But maybe somebody had the same problem and found a way to solve it? I wouldn't mind a solution that uses python code too.

Comment: Well, as a human I have problems to distinguish them. I think it is not possible without a dictionary of possibilities.

Comment: There's no sure-fire way to do that.  Even a human will have difficulty for some cases.  You could use various heuristics like trying various combinations of open/close and seeing if they result in unlikely results (like a space after an open quote), but you won't really be able to know which way is right until you try different ways.

Comment: One method you could employ is using the proximity of the quotes to a character. Usually apostrophes will come after the end of a word i.e. no space before it, and they usually do not end a sentence. Single quotes begin at the start of a word i.e. no space after it and then after the end of a sentence. So armed with that, you could decide to settle on considering single quotes as ones that come at the start of a word and the last one that comes after the end of a word

Comment: @BernardoGO I feared that. Sadly the dictionary approach, even if it was feasible to build it, is not viable because a word like "dogs'" could be either a saxon genitive or a normal plural at the end of a quote.

Comment: @smac89 it will work only for simple cases, not in the one in my test string

Comment: I suspected as much. I think you may have to go for a more intelligent approach i.e. some sort of language parser - [Parsey McParseface](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet)

Comment: @smac89 Yep, we are going into the Big Shots realm =D I can't afford training an AI ;P... Interesting link though, thank'you.

Comment: You can match those that are inside a word with `\b'\b`. However, you won't  know for sure in 100% cases since `boys' game` will be a false positive.

Comment: Well, beginning of word should be easy - `\B'\b` (I do not know a word starting with a single apostrophe), but end of word is not that evident.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : a word starting with apostrophe, for example, is 'em (go get 'em all!). It's even worse than I thought, because we can't be sure about openers either..